# PHP: Explode two delimiters with two foreach loop

Tags: php, loops, foreach, explode

I am trying to get two foreach loop by explode with two delimiters `<>` and `"\n"` but getting error. `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Here is my code

```
<?php

    $specifications = $scooter_meta->get_the_value('specifications');

    $titles = explode('<>', $specifications);

    $descs = explode("\n", $specifications);

    echo '<dl>';

    foreach($titles as $title => $descs){

        echo '<dt>' . $title . '</dt>';

        foreach($descs as $desc){
            echo '<dd>' . $desc . '</dd>';
        }

    }

    echo '</dl>';

?>
```

The value entering into textarea something like this `Title here<>this is the first scooter ever made.
Title here 2<>another line for specification` In fact I would like to make it like `<title 1> here detail text`

Thanks a lot

Comment: `var_dump()` the stuff you are trying to use in your `foreach` loops and see if they contain what you think they conatin. (hint: probably not)

Comment: I am getting this output with var_dump() `array(3) { [0]=> string(10) "Title here" [1]=> string(50) "this is the first scooter ever made. Title here 2" [2]=> string(30) "another line for specification" } `

Comment: what exactly is separated by \n?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

actually you should do something like this

```
<?php

$specifications = $scooter_meta->get_the_value('specifications');

$descs = explode("\n", $specifications);

echo '<dl>';

foreach($descs as $desc){

    $title = explode('<>', $desc);

    echo '<dt>' . $title[0] . '</dt>';
    for($i=1; $i<=count($title); $i++){
        echo '<dd>' . $title[$i] . '</dd>';
    }

}

echo '</dl>';

?>
```

Comment: wonderful this is working perfectly without any issue. Before selecting your answer can you please know me if I want to wrap title with `<title here>` instead of `title herr<>` is it the same thing or different process?

Comment: you mean if you have the text like `<Title here>this is the first scooter ever made.` ? or you want output to be `<Title here>` ?

Comment: Exactly instead of `the title here<>this is the first scooter ever made.` is it possible to make like `<the title here>this is the first scooter ever made` means wrapping title with less than and grater than sign which makes more sense for the user

Comment: just change to `$title = explode('>', $desc);` and `echo '<dt>' . str_replace('<', '', $title[0]) . '</dt>';`

Comment: Wonderful. Yesterday itself I said you all people are great.. thank you so much to you and all other who tried to help me.. thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

The `$descs` variable isn't an array because the first foreach loop sets `$descs`.

See this line :

```
foreach($titles as $title => $descs){
```

Comment: can you please give me some more detail how to do? I am not very experienced so need some detail help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$specifications = $scooter_meta->get_the_value('specifications');

$titles = explode('<>', $specifications);

echo '<dl>';

foreach($titles as $title => $descs){

    echo '<dt>' . $title . '</dt>';

    $descs = explode("\n", $descs);

    foreach($descs as $desc){
        echo '<dd>' . $desc . '</dd>';
    }

}

echo '</dl>';
```

Comment: This is working fine unless its giving array number like 0, 1, 2 see this `0
    Title here
1
    this is the first scooter ever made. 
    Title here 2
2
    another line for specification`